# Error 1175 (HY000): You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE EXTERNALCONNECTIONTYPE
SET
    ATTRIBUTEDESCMAP = 'BlahBlahBlah',
    ATTRIBUTEKEY =  'BlahBlah',
    ENCRYPTEDATTRIBUTES = 'BlahBlah'
WHERE 
 EXTERNALCONNECTIONTYPEKEY IN (SELECT DISTINCT EXTERNALCONNECTIONTYPE FROM EXTERNALCONNECTION WHERE MSCONNECTORVERSION LIKE "SFTPConnector/%" and EXTERNALCONNECTIONKEY <> 0);
```

I tried running this query. I am getting an sql_safe_updates error and I want to execute this query without turning off the sql_safe_updates. It's working fine when I remove the inner query and hard code like the following:

```
UPDATE EXTERNALCONNECTIONTYPE
SET
    ATTRIBUTEDESCMAP = 'BlahBlahBlah',
    ATTRIBUTEKEY =  'BlahBlah',
    ENCRYPTEDATTRIBUTES = 'BlahBlah'
WHERE 
 EXTERNALCONNECTIONTYPEKEY = 54;
```

Comment: Please do not tag lots of RDBMS. Only tag the one that you are using. I have removed them all and you can [edit] your question to include the one that is relevant.

Comment: Do you have any column common in `EXTERNALCONNECTIONTYPE`  and
`EXTERNALCONNECTION`
OR Any primary key in `EXTERNALCONNECTIONTYPE` ?

Comment: You may add fake condition by primary key column: ```.. AND EXTERNALCONNECTIONTYPEKEY <= XXXXX;```, where XXXXX is maxvalue for column's datatype.

Answer (score 1):

From your subquery; we already have;

```
XTERNALCONNECTIONTYPE.EXTERNALCONNECTIONTYPEKEY = EXTERNALCONNECTION.EXTERNALCONNECTIONTYPE;
```

So,
We can modify the query above to use `join` instead of a `subquery` to avoid `Error 1175`

```
UPDATE EXTERNALCONNECTIONTYPE
JOIN EXTERNALCONNECTION ON EXTERNALCONNECTIONTYPE.EXTERNALCONNECTIONTYPEKEY = EXTERNALCONNECTION.EXTERNALCONNECTIONTYPE
SET
    EXTERNALCONNECTIONTYPE.ATTRIBUTEDESCMAP = 'BlahBlahBlah',
    EXTERNALCONNECTIONTYPE.ATTRIBUTEKEY = 'BlahBlah',
    EXTERNALCONNECTIONTYPE.ENCRYPTEDATTRIBUTES = 'BlahBlah'
WHERE
    EXTERNALCONNECTION.MSCONNECTORVERSION LIKE 'SFTPConnector/%'
    AND EXTERNALCONNECTION.EXTERNALCONNECTIONKEY <> 0;
```